# How to read a file from server multiple times with objectinputstream in Java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, file-io

```
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(c.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(c.getInputStream());                

            File file = new File("lol.txt");
            if(!file.exists()){
                file.createNewFile();
            }                

            byte[] textBytes;
            while((textBytes = (byte[])ois.readObject()) != null){                  
                Files.write(file.toPath(), textBytes);                  
            }
            //do stuff...
            byte[] textBytes;
            while((textBytes = (byte[])ois.readObject()) != null){                  
                Files.write(file.toPath(), textBytes);                  
            }
```

How can I read a file on a server multiple times? Should this code work? Will it not get stuck in the first loop check?

The server is writing it to the client like this.

```
                byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(fp.toPath());
                oos.writeObject(fileBytes);
                oos.flush();
```

Comment: Is c an instance of `java.net.Socket`? And oos an `ObjectOutputStream` connected to a the Server's socket?

Comment: Yes c is an instance of java.net.Socket and oos is connected to the server.

Comment: NB Your read loop is invalid. `readObject()` doesn't return null at end of stream. It can do that any time you wrote a null. You need to catch `EOFException`.

Answer (score 0):

A repeatable read on a Socket's `InputStream` is not possible, because it is a buffer based, blocking implementation, using a `descriptor` to indicate where the current position in the buffer is.

When you read from the `InputStream` the `descriptor` moves the amount of bytes you have read. It's not possible to rewind the `descriptor` to the previous position, because the read bytes maybe already overwritten by new received bytes.

You server client communication must be in this way 
*(I use the following abbreviations: S -> a Server, C -> a Client)*:

```
C: Request file from S
S: Send file to C
C: Request file from S
S: Send file to C
(and so on)
```